# How to overwrite cc, bcc addresses of a mailable object

Tags: php, email, laravel-7, laravel-mail

I work on a Laravel 7 webbapp. The apps sends out to emails to customers with some internal addresses on bcc.

However when I work on the development instance of the application, I want to reroute all emails automatically to my support email address. The below code works for rerouting the "to" address, but does not work for the "cc" and "bcc" addresses. Supposedly because those addresses are filled in by Laravel after I'm trying to overwrite them.

Please propose a solution to this problem, preferable without changing every mailable class. Thanks!

```
class GNGMail
{

    public $to;
    public $mail;
    
    public function __construct($to, Mailable $mail) {

        $this->to = $to;
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }
    
    //sends out an email message
    public function send()
    {
        
        $mailMode = config('mail.mode');
        
        // doing nothing if email is disabled
        if ($mailMode === 'disabled') return;   

        //if we are in dev mode, we reroute all emails to support
        if ($mailMode === 'dev') {
            $this->to = '****@********.***';
            if (!empty($this->mail->cc)) 
                $this->mail->cc = '****@********.***';
            if (!empty($this->mail->bcc)) 
                $this->mail->bcc = '****@********.***';
        }

        Mail::to($this->to)
            ->send($this->mail);

    } 
}
```